# What's the correctly way to make Postfix run permanently on Lion (not server)

Tags: macos, plist, email

I can start Postfix temporarily with:

```
$ sudo launchctl
launchd% start org.postfix.master
```

However, Console.app shows that it only runs for a short time:

```
26/11/11 2:00:55.710 PM postfix/master: master exit time has arrived
```

I think the file  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist needs to be updated to make Postfix run permanently, but I haven't found the answer yet.

What's the correct way of getting Postfix starting at boot time and running permanently?

**Update**
In order to edit the file as recommended by the selected answer, I first converted it to XML.

```
plutil  -convert xml1 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

Then just edited it with Vim:

```
sudo vim /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

I had issues trying to get Xcode to edit the file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following changes worked for me:

1. Remove the following two elements from `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist`:

   > ```
   > <string>-e</string>
   > <string>60</string>
   > ```

   This will stop it exiting after 60 seconds.
2. Add the following element as a child of the `<dict>...</dict>` element in the same plist file:

   > ```
   > <key>KeepAlive</key>
   > <true/>
   > ```
3. Reload the file:

   > ```
   > sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist 
   > sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
   > ```

postfix should now be running as a daemon.

The above works on Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite and El Capitan. For systems that have System Integrity Protection (El Capitan and later) there are two options:

1. Copying `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist` to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.custom.plist`, changing `org.postfix.master` to `org.postfix.custom` and then unloading and loading as above.
2. Disabling SIP (using `csrutil`), making the edits and then re-enabling SIP.

**Note:** With High Sierra and Mojave, the configuration file is `com.apple.postfix.master.plist` instead of `org.postfix.custom.plist`.

Comment: Worked for me on Mavericks, but I had to put the full file path in to load it: sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist

Comment: There was a `cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons` line in there before the `unload` and `load` that may have been missed. I inlined the full path to make it clearer.

Comment: i had to type "sudo postfix start" to mke it words instead of launchtl load stuff from mjturner; don't know why ...

Comment: On El Capitan, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist` is no longer editable. Suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisWithers I've added some info. Basically, disable SIP, make the edits and re-enable. You'll need to boot from rescue media before you can enable/disable SIP though.

Comment: @mjturner - disable the sip? nope nope nope... Much better is just to create a new .plist that you own in /Library/LaunchDaemons/

Comment: @ChrisWithers Fair comment (unfortunately your suggested edit was rejected, not by me). I prefer the disable/edit/enable approach so that it's more obvious but yours is also valid.

Comment: @mjturner - yeah, that's weird. I didn't get any notification, and it's a bit sad. Care to make the same edit?

Comment: @ChrisWithers Yep, will edit my answer this evening and include your suggestion. 

Comment: @mjturner On High Sierra, `org.postfix.master.plist` is renamed to `com.apple.postfix.master.plist`. Maybe you may want to add that to the answer.

Comment: I had to add `<key>RunAtLoad</key> <true/>` in order to get it to startup on boot (on High Sierra)

Comment: @mjturner: Putting the custom plist in LaunchDaemons doesn't start the custom daemon, because the original is already running, effectively taking precedence. So every time I restart my computer, I have to first unload the original daemon and then load the custom manually using `launchctl` from Terminal. Is there a way to make macOS (I'm on 10.12) run the modified version of Postfix automatically on startup without messing with SIP?