# running email server (postfix?) on plain Mavericks (NOT server)

Tags: macos, email

I need to run a very simple email server on a plain (non-OSX Server) Mavericks box (Mac mini). All I need to do is be able to receive email with attachments, send it to a Perl/Python script, and send simple reports via email from the Perl/Python script. Basically, my script processed the email, including the attachment, and either sends an email report to the sender or to a mailing list. I've done this on an old Linux box with postfix, but I need to move this to a newer/faster machine - this Mac mini running Mavericks. When I try to search on this, everything I get is for OSX Server, but I don't have OSX Server. I know from experience that you can't follow regular Linux instructions for OSX, it's too different. I need this server to start itself whenever the device restarts, as well. This is a protected server on a LAN and will never receive email from outside, so I don't have security concerns. I need the simplest, most robust setup I can find. Doesn't have to be postfix, but it's what I've used before. The traffic load will be very small (maybe 20 emails a day, max).

Update: This is the recipe I used for my old CentOS box. As I recall, it took me a while to get it working. I'm looking at it again now, but I'm honestly hoping there's a simpler solution.

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correctly way to make Postfix run permanently on Lion (not server)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32228/whats-the-correctly-way-to-make-postfix-run-permanently-on-lion-not-server) - the answer there applies to Mavericks too