# Postfix SSL/TLS certificates issue

Tags: email, ssl

I'm trying to set up postfix to send mail through Gmail's SMTP server on port 587. Here's what I've put in my `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

However, I'm running into TLS problem since `/etc/postfix/cacert.pem`, which seems to be suggested everywhere online, doesn't really exist on my system (OS X 10.9.3).

**Therefore, what is the right CAfile to use?** Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

On a side note, for now I'm using the workaround

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

which works. However, I suppose this is a cheap fix, and I'm worried about the security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option specifies where the root certificates of the trusted issuers are located.

On OS X they are stored in the Keychain.

You can extract them with

```
$ sudo security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain > /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

And then

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**Edit** Keep in mind that when Apple updates the root certificates in the Keychain you will have to export them again.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and clarification. It worked.

Comment: Hmm, do you know how often Apple updates root certificates? I'll run a cron job for that.

Comment: Also note that Google publishes a .pem file of root CA certs you should trust when connecting to Google. It's available from their PKI FAQ here: https://pki.google.com/faq.html. The PEM file itself is here: https://pki.google.com/roots.pem

Comment: @KevinSayHi Actually I don't really know (I never checked)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) to send email through your Google account on modern OS Xs by adding the following lines to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (eg. by `sudo sh -c 'cat >> /etc/postfix/main.cf'`):

```
relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
```

Then [generate an application-specific password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) and use it to create the contents of `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` (eg. by `sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`):

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 my_email_address@gmail.com:my_app_spec_password
```

(Remember to fix permissions, eg. `sudo chmod 440 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`).

Start the postfix server (if it is not already started)

```
$ sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

or (if postfix is already started) reload the configuration

```
$ sudo postfix reload
```

Now your can send email from the command line:

```
$ mailx -s 'Test email 1' my_email_address@gmail.com
Testing, testing...^D
```

The mail server [stops again at some point](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32228/whats-the-correctly-way-to-make-postfix-run-permanently-on-lion-not-server), so you might need to start it again the next time you need to use it:

```
$ sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```