# Send mail from OS X without email account

Tags: email

On linux, I use exim4 to send mail to a public email address. I don't have to authenticate or anything. It pretends its noreply@example.com and sends it to someone@example.com.  Is it possible to do the same on OS X?

I have a cron job, and I want to send mail from the root user as noreply@example.com like with my linux box. I looked up postfix configuration as it seems to be the method used, but all the examples require authentication. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: To send an email, your ISP must allow outbound emails. If it doesn’t, then your message may not go through without you setting up the terminal email program to send messages through another server. Some ISPs will block outbound emails in an attempt to curb spam messages originating from their networks.

Comment: @ Buscar웃SD: BTW the problem isn't about an ISP blocking but about how to send a basic email with a given address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's no problem in sending emails like that from OS X.

First, you'll need to [configure postfix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32228/whats-the-correctly-way-to-make-postfix-run-permanently-on-lion-not-server/32569#32569) to relay emails. Once you've done that, you'll need to create the script that sends the email. I'm not sure what method you're using to send email on the Linux system, but something very similar should work on OS X, for example, using `mailx`.

Assuming that your upstream mail provider (the system your OS X system is relaying mail through, ie the mail relay) doesn't require authentication, you won't need to configure mail authentication.